# Responsive table of bootstrap showing blur in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5.7

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7. When I use 'table-responsive' class for the table it shows clear and properly in the desktop view but in mobile view, it shows blur text. Words are not showing clearly.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table"> 
    <tr>
        <th> Sr.No </th>
        <th> Company Name </th>
        <th> Contact No. </th>
        <th> Address </th>                                    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> ABC </th>
        <th> 1234567890 </th>
        <th> India </th>                                    
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> XYZ </th>
        <th> 0123456789 </th>
        <th> India </th>                                    
    </tr>                   
  </table>
</div>
```

I want that, it shows a clear view of the table in mobile also just like the desktop view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table"> 
          <tr>
            <th> Sr.No </th>
            <th> Company Name </th>
            <th> Contact No. </th>
            <th> Address </th>                                    
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th> 1 </th>
            <th> ABC </th>
            <th> 1234567890 </th>
            <th> India </th>                                    
          </tr>       
          <tr>
            <th> 2 </th>
            <th> XYZ </th>
            <th> 0123456789 </th>
            <th> India </th>                                    
          </tr>                   
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure the exact reason why it is looking blurry but when i removed the border form `.table-responsive` it worked.

Comment: You're welcome! If you think it's helpful or technical enough then please approve and vote it up, so that the other members can get benefit from your question:)

Comment: Hi @nazifa rashid,  I voted it but it shows the message, "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score." My reputations are only 11.

Comment: okay no worries! if you feel like approving and vote it up, feel free to do that!

Comment: Hi @nazifa rashid, I just had 16 Reputations now, so I am able to vote now. I voted for your answer. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You're most welcome :) Also as you're new you can also approve the best answer by clicking on the tick mark

Comment: Hi, @nazifa rashid ok fine. Clicked on tick mark also. Thanks.